# How to display output of iperf cmd prompt in textbox

Tags: c#, command-prompt, iperf

I am using iperf-2.0.5-2-win32 tool to find network bandwidth. I have written codes in c# which opens the cmd prompt, pass iperf parameters to start server side & client side. iperf-2.0.5-2-win32 exe will not open directly, need to open through cmd prompt only.
At present the output(Transfer rate & Bandwidth) is displaying on cmd prompt itself. I want these output to be displayed in textbox
I have tried StreamReader also. But it takes null, I have also tried OutputDataReceived Event, its also taking null.
Found few codes for ipconfig & ping.but those were not working with iperf codes.

```
button_click event(),
{
Process Client_proc = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo Client_command = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe"); 
string ip = txtIP.Text;
Client_command.CreateNoWindow = true;
Client_command.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Client_command.WorkingDirectory = @"E:\Iperf\RunEXE_Through_Application\iperf-2.0.5-2-win32";
Client_command.Arguments = "/c START iperf -c " + ip;
Client_proc.StartInfo = Client_command;
Client_command.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Client_command.UseShellExecute = false;
Client_proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(Client_proc_OutputDataReceived);
Client_proc.Start(); 
Client_proc.BeginOutputReadLine(); 
Client_proc.WaitForExit();
}

void Client_proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Data != null)
{
string newLine = e.Data.Trim() + Environment.NewLine;
MethodInvoker append = () => txtOutput.Text += newLine;
txtOutput.BeginInvoke(append);
}
}
```

Plz help me.Earlier responses are appreciated
Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it takes null"?

Comment: @hSchroedl- if i keep break point and check value of E.Data() is null"
if i keep break point and check value of e.Data() in Client_proc_OutputDataReceived is null

Comment: Hmm. I tried iperf myself, but I can't get an output even if I lauch it from from a cmd window... so debugging this is kinda difficult for me. I recommend you execute it from the command line, like you normally would, and see what output that gives you. One other possible problem I noticed is that "START" will open another window/process, which you would not have any listeners/streamreaders attached to. Thats all I have, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

you use this complete code for your disposal
It is not perfect (some problems when using multiple streams )

```
public void RunProcess(string FileName, string Arguments, bool EventWhenExit )
{
    process = new Process();

    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OnDataReceivedEvent);
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = false;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = FileName; // Gets or sets the application or document to start.
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments;//Gets or sets the set of command-line arguments to use when starting the application      
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    if (EventWhenExit)
    {
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        process.Exited += new EventHandler(myprocess_Exited);/*New line */

    }

    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    PID = process.Id;


}

private void myprocess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    process.Refresh();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    onProcessEnd(this, "ENDOF " + Proc.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Process exsiting ");
}


private void OnDataReceivedEvent(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

    string OutputFromProcess = e.Data;
    //fire event to event handler class for further use
    onDataOutputFromProcess(this, OutputFromProcess, Proc.ToString());
}
```

than in your GUI layer you should bind to `onDataOutputFromProcess` event 
there you should have something like

```
if (screenToPrint.InvokeRequired) //&& this.Visible)
{
    try
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<AppendToScreenParam>(AppendTextFullConfig), new object[] { append });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    return;
}
else
{
    screenToPrint.SelectionFont = font;
    screenToPrint.SelectionColor = append.Color;
    //screenToPrint.AppendText(append.Message);
    string TextToPrint = string.Format("{0}\n", append.Message);
    screenToPrint.AppendText(TextToPrint);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because iperf process is returning error. Subscribe the `ErrorDataReceived` event with `Client_proc.ErrorDataReceived += Client_proc_ErrorDataReceived;` and see the results. If command returns error, you can see the error message as output.

```
void Client_proc_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        this.txtOutput.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { this.txtOutput.Text = e.Data; }));
    }
}
```

Comment: @CuriousPen-No CuriousPen, I get the output in the same command prompt,I dont get any error message.I wish to redirect the command prompt output to a textbox.
I am stuck in this part. Could u plz look into this

Comment: @user1244453 What is strange is I can get all the command line output from ErrorDataReceivent event. You can try with -v or --help parameters with iperf command for example. All output is written to ErrorStream